# My CSS and JS external files are not working in my project

Tags: javascript, php, css, url, server

I have a simple project with that files structure:

[image: image of my structure]

But my CSS and JS files are not loading...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">

<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Yes Barmar,  in the browser console shows it can't find the main.css and main.js files

Comment: It should also show the full URL, so you should be able to tell what folder it's looking in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/www/public/css/main.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/www/public/js/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

May be this should work :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: did not work :/ apparently it's a url error that doesn't load my external js css files via index.php idk...

Comment: did u put the css sheet in the header section and js end of the body ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the below should works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">

<script src="../js/main.js"></script>
```

Add two dots instead of one.

For more information read: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Conclusion.**
I managed to solve the problem. But I had to point to the entire root of the directories. This way it worked.

```
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./www/public/css/main.css">
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js" integrity="sha512-pHVGpX7F/27yZ0ISY+VVjyULApbDlD0/X0rgGbTqCE7WFW5MezNTWG/dnhtbBuICzsd0WQPgpE4REBLv+UqChw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="./www/public/js/main.js"></script>
```